# Why can I only request to migrate to this Meta?

Tags: bug

When voting to close a question as off topic, there's an option to vote as off topic because the question belongs to a different site in the SE network. But when choosing that, I only have the possibility to choose Phil Meta, and not actually a different site in the network.

Why is that?